# @Published state is not getting updated, even though I called it in init() - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

It seems I still don't quite understand it, can someone please explain it, not only tell me what's wrong. So I have declared my @Published, I created an init so every time it's called it fetches the data from the DB, why is it not refreshing on the View?

The data was only refreshed after I quit the simulator and relunched. Here's the code:

```
final class DataStorePersistanceHandler: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userWallets: List<Wallet> = List<Wallet>()
    
    let authSessionManager = AuthSessionManager()
    
    init() {
        getWallets()
    }
    
    // MARK: Get local/online user wallets
    func getWallets() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let user = self.authSessionManager.getUser()
            
            Amplify.DataStore.query(User.self, byId: user.userId) {
                switch $0 {
                case .success(let wallet):
                    if let userWithWallets = wallet {
                        if let wallets = userWithWallets.wallets {
                            self.userWallets = wallets
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No wallets found for this user")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("User not found - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling it in the view:

```
@EnvironmentObject var dataStorePersistanceHandler: DataStorePersistanceHandler

...

if(dataStorePersistanceHandler.userWallets.count == 0) {
    someView()
} else {
    Text("SomeText")
}
```

Comment: Are you actually assigning `self.userWallets = wallets`? (maybe the inner `if` is false). Are you using `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject` for the `dataStorePersistanceHandler` property inside the view?

Comment: @NewDev Yes, I'm trying to assign the database value that is fetched to a Published variable so the view state is updated when the DB value changes. I'm also declaring it like this: `@EnvironmentObject var dataStorePersistanceHandler: DataStorePersistanceHandler` in the view that has the if statement: `if(dataStorePersistanceHandler.userWallets.count == 0) {`. What do you mean false? I tested it first with no value in the DB, and then I added a value and didn't refresh, then re-lunched app and the view had the value

Comment: @Arturo are you sure `query` sure subscribe you to updates? I expect it to be executed only once

Comment: It is execute only once (the query). I don't have any rpc call or queues, it's a database get request. This is what happens or at least my intention: a user creates a new wallet in another view (now the db contains 1 item) when I go to see the wallets in another view it's there because it was Published (in SwiftUI). For this I was forcing the DB refresh by doing the init. Am I doing all this completly wrong? @Philip

Comment: @Arturo check out when you init gets called. Place a breakpoint and make sure it's after new item is created

Comment: `query` performs **one** database request. For a dynamic update you need `publisher`

Comment: I have another, likely unrelated question: how can you make it that `self.authSessionManager.getUser()` synchronously returns a user? I would guess, this is the user who has been signed in. So, at least at one point in time in our app, there is no such user yet, and this getter may fail fatal.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I agree, I debugged it and it gets called even before the fetch user gets called. I'm looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `self.authSessionManager.getUser()` call is really synchronous and `Amplify.DataStore.query(...)` is asynchronous and `DataStorePersistanceHandler` environment object created and injected correctly, try the following:

```
func getWallets() {
        let user = self.authSessionManager.getUser()
        
        Amplify.DataStore.query(User.self, byId: user.userId) {
            switch $0 {
            case .success(let wallet):
                if let userWithWallets = wallet {
                    if let wallets = userWithWallets.wallets {
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {               // << here !!
                          self.userWallets = wallets
                       }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No wallets found for this user")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("User not found - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: init is called on the main queue anyway, but API callback might be called on work queue, but published property must be set on main UI queue to make UI updated.*

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that when you start your app, "DataStorePersistanceHandler" is
created and calls "getWallets()" in the "init()". Since you don't call "getWallets()" anywhere else,
that is all the data you get, just this first db query. "getWallets()" does not get called again by magic
when you use "DataStorePersistanceHandler". You have to manually do it yourself to update the
"@Published var userWallets". That is why you get the "new" data when you start the app again.

Somewhere in your code you say you add a new value to the db, at that point you have to
call "getWallets()" to update the "@Published var userWallets". Not do "init()" again. Your view should then refresh.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion for local changes, but what if I have 2 devices? I'm using 1 and someone creates an object? How do I refresh that? I was thinking on using onAppear() but that would create too many queries on the db

Comment: When you have 2 or more devices, then you could use the Amplify cloud.  
Once you enable cloud syncing, then add a subscription to the application using 
the Combine framework and Amplify.DataStore.publisher(for: User.self) to receive any updates by any other devices.
There is some docs for ios here: 

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/add-api/q/integration/ios#add-a-subscription